# How to do shipment to custom shipping carrier?

Tags: php, magento

I need to add a local carrier , The only options that are available for carriers are, DHL, FEDEX , UPS and USPS. 
I need to do shipment in checkout.
Invoice is generated in magento one page checkout.
Is there any way to do shipment in checkout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources on how to create new shipping module:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks Ovidiu. I have created new module referring given links.  I need to submit order to local carrier using soap method and this order submit should be called after order creation. Is it possible?

Comment: @RV Any solution about your problem ?